# Process builder failing with newly added global picklist value and new lead source value

Tags: process-builder

We updated our "First Source" global picklist and our "Lead Source" value to include 'Salesforce'. We do not have record types on leads, contacts, or accounts (opportunity record types were updated to include the new values). I updated process builder to set the first source and lead source to the 'Salesforce' value for the fields when they are NULL but I get the error below.

> Error element myRule_5_A1 (FlowRecordUpdate). The flow tried to update
> these records: 00Q1U00000WQKjxUAH. This error occurred:
> INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST: First Source: bad value for
> restricted picklist field: Lead Source.

Our lead source field and first source field mirror each other except for the fact that first source is a global picklist which I recently added the new value.

Comment: did you assign the new value to all record types?  If you missed a record type and the PB tries to set the value on a record with that type, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned the new value of 'Salesforce' in your question, but the error you pasted doesn't mention it. The error says that you are trying to set the First Source picklist to the value of "Lead Source". I supect that "Lead Source" is not a value in your picklist. Perhaps you are trying to set First Source picklist to whatever value is in the Lead Source picklist, but you accidentally are setting it to the text value of "Lead Source" instead.